# Xamarin Data Bindings error System.InvalidCastExeption: Specified cast Invalid

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to retrieve data from sql server then bind to xamarin forms entry I am using Shared Project

My problem after Log In and open new content page (Main Page) there is an error  System.InvalidCastExeption: Specified cast Invalid 
then my Main Page is empty.

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace App10
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {          
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //entry

            //connectionstring
            string serverIp = "192.168.43.16,1433";
            string username = "un";
            string password = "pass";
            string databaseName = "db";

            string dbConnectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};User ID={1};Password={2};Database={3};", serverIp, username, password, databaseName);
            IDbConnection dbcon;
            using (dbcon = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    dbcon.Open();
                    using (IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        string sql =
                            "SELECT ADMITBED_ID,AdmittingNumber,FullName,RoomID,DaysofStay,LastCensusDate,LastTimeCensus " +
                            "FROM AdmittedWardRoomManagement WHERE Status = 'ADMITTED' AND FullName = 'Full Name'";
                        dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
                        using (IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {    
                                FullName.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name"); \\error i think here at bindings
                                string id = (string)reader["ADMITBED_ID"];
                                FullName.BindingContext = new { Name = id };
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Daily Census", Convert.ToString(ex), "OK");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does it give the exception?

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: Also, there is no column Name in your query

Comment: the expection error here FullName.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Remove this line

```
FullName.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");
string id = (string)reader["ADMITBED_ID"];
FullName.BindingContext = new { Name = id };
```

change with this

```
string id = reader["ADMITBED_ID"].ToString();
```